# Google AMP Purge CDN, When the Source Updated

Tags: amp-html

Can we do anything to update the AMP CDN to purge specific pages or entire domain cached HTML?

Comment: There might be some issues with updating the cached version of the pages but that will show in time. For now, the Google Cache will make sure that your users will get content super fast. You can see the thread [here](https://responsivedesign.is/articles/whats-the-deal-with-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp)

Answer (score 2):

You can update the contents of the cache on a URL by URL basis using the update ping mechanism: https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping

This involves making a GET request to the AMP cache URL for your content.

Answer (score 0):

I tied in the [update-ping api call](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping) to our CMS when we publish or unpublish a story. So everytime we update or remove a page we call the update-ping API so we can update the page cache or remove the page cache depending on what the user has done. You cannot (as of now, could change in the future) cache or clear the entire cache of an entire domain. No wild cards allowed currently.

Hope this helps.