# Is it possible to force google amp html pages to refresh?

Tags: amp-html

Pretty sure i know the answer but cant find definitive yes/no.

Is there a way e.g. api call to make a page stored in google's amp cache to force it to get new copy of that page?

Editorial want to know when they update a page in cms that google gets updates too.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this: let Google do it and/or do it yourself. If you let Google do it, it's a black box - only Google knows how they manage the data they cache. If you are deploying data in your own CDN, well - no need to bore you with the obvious answer there.

To answer your specific question: no, there is no API to force a new copy of an AMP page in the Google CDN. However, if you use `http://schema.org/dateModified` in the AMP document and keep your sitemap up-to-date, you'll present the Google crawler with data it needs to accurately refresh its CDN.

See also: [Google AMP Purge CDN, When the Source Updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348972/google-amp-purge-cdn-when-the-source-updated?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Jay. I have added the dateModified. I was after some kind of definitive answer to if they had a api which i couldnt find any doco regarding so assumed it wasnt possible, now I have backup of that fact.

Comment: "[When a user requests an AMP document from the Google AMP Cache, the cache automatically requests updates in order to be able to serve fresh content for the next user once the content has been cached. With this model, updates to AMP documents propagate automatically and quickly; few users will see the non-updated version after your update.](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#google-amp-cache-updates)"

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can easily [force the Google AMP Cache to update your AMP page](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping):

> The most effective way to update the version of any AMP document stored in the Google AMP Cache is to access that document using the [AMP Cache URL format](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#amp-cache-url-format). The Google AMP Cache automatically requests the latest version of the AMP document from its origin and serves the updated version to the next user.

For example, to refresh http://example.com/amp_document.html, simply navigate to https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/example.com/amp_document.html.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's more involved that just calling a URL however because you also have to create and pass a digital signature as a request parameter. I created a script to automate this: https://www.takaitra.com/amp-cache-update-script/

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct.  Make sure to read through https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview for full details.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API called [update-ping](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping) which is used for this very purposes. When a page on our site is published, republished or unpublished we call this API passing the page info it needs. At this point we are either adding the page to cache, updating the page in cache or removing the page entirely from the Google AMP cache. Things to note with this is there are no wildcards. This is done on a page by page basis. I just hooked the update-ping API call into our CMS publishing functionality. Now when publishing of any sorts happens we add, update or remove the cached url. This insures that the cache always represents the latest changes even if that means the page is going away. Bye bye cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `udate-ping` is deprecated, now use this: https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache

Comment: @Flo I think you misspelled update in the comment.